# C++ error, trying to create a simple directory search function

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

So here's what's going on. I'm trying to create this little function I pretty much just copy-pasted from this wonderful place called stackoverflow.com. Only thing I added was the if statement in it to search for a string with a specific ending (in my case it's '.kbin'). Once it finds that file it should add it to the end of a vector list thing.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <filesystem>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

void GetListOfFiles(std::string path, std::vector<std::string>* files)
{
    for (const auto& entry : fs::recursive_directory_iterator(path)) {
        if (entry.subentry(entry.find_last_of(".") + 1) == "kbin")
            &files->push_back(entry.path());
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::string path = argv[1];
    std::vector<std::string> files;
    GetListOfFiles(path, files);
}
```

The problem occurs when I try to compile this. Maybe I'm just doing something wrong but for whatever reason the compiler says this:

1. error: ‘const class std::filesystem::__cxx11::directory_entry’ has no member named ‘substr’
   15 |   if(entry.substr(entry.find_last_of(".") + 1) == "kbin")
2. error: ‘const class std::filesystem::__cxx11::directory_entry’ has no member named ‘find_last_of’
   15 |   if(entry.substr(entry.find_last_of(".") + 1) == "kbin")
3. error: lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand
   16 |    &files->push_back(entry.path());

Please help.
I'm using g++ version 9.3.0 and am compiling with the next command `g++ main.cpp -o main -lstdc++fs -std=c++17`.

Comment: Not whatever reason, because there are syntax issues with your code. Do you see a `substr()` function here? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_entry

Comment: First thing to do: indent your code properly.

Comment: I think you want entry.path().extension().string() to get the string of the extension.

Comment: @drescherjm Šefeee, that did the trick

Comment: I was going to post an answer but my version of Visual Studio Community 2019 does not recognize the filesystem library even when I enable c++17 so I could not test and gave up.